# react-native not detected my physical device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

adb devices detect my physical phone but react-native run-android command open my emulator..
and whenever i put this command npx react-native run-android --deviceId=97e2bc510706 it shows error no emulator or android device connected   [I WILL GET THIS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4k3D.jpg)

Comment: Have you enabled usb debugging on your device?

Answer (score 0):

if you have android studio , open your project's android folder in android studio and run in your physical device and in vs code run command npx react-native start and if you are using mobile hotspot then open your app and shake your device or long press minimize button , go to setting and in port add your ip (for example : ,196.168.0.1:8081) after ip put your port number.

hope it will work ...!

Answer (score 0):

Always remember sdk path not contain any space in my case my username of computer is shrivastava ji so there is space in my username so remove space in your username or file name or change the sdk path where path have no space